# RavenTimeoutPersistence error when starting NserviceBus.host

Tags: nservicebus, ravendb

When I try & start one of my services I get this error:
`There is no index named: RavenTimeoutPersistence/TimeoutDataSortedByTime`

Stacktrace:

> Unhandled Exception: Magnum.StateMachine.StateMachineException:
>   Exception occurred in Topshelf.Internal.ServiceControlle
>   r`1[[NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows.WindowsHost, NServiceBus.Host,
>   Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9fc3864 79f8a226c]]
>   during state Initial while handling OnStart ---> System.Exception:
>   Exception when starting endpoint, error h as been logged. Reason:
>   There is no index named: RavenTimeoutPersistence/TimeoutDataSortedByTime --->
>   System.InvalidOper ationException: There is no index named:
>   RavenTimeoutPersistence/TimeoutDataSortedByTime    at
>   Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.DirectQuery(String index,
>   IndexQuery query, String operationUrl, String[] inc ludes)    at
>   Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.<>c__DisplayClass37.<Query>b__36(String
>   u)    at Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.TryOperation[T](Func`2
>   operation, String operationUrl, Boolean avoidThrowing,  T& result)
>   at
>   Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.ExecuteWithReplication[T](String
>   method, Func`2 operation)    at
>   Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.Query(String index, IndexQuery
>   query, String[] includes)    at
>   Raven.Client.Document.AbstractDocumentQuery`2.ExecuteActualQuery()
>   at Raven.Client.Document.AbstractDocumentQuery`2.get_QueryResult()
>
>   at
>   Raven.Client.Linq.RavenQueryProviderProcessor`1.ExecuteQueryTProjection
>   at Raven.Client.Linq.RavenQueryProviderProcessor`1.Execute(Expression
>   expression)    at
>   Raven.Client.Linq.RavenQueryProvider`1.Execute(Expression expression) 
>   at
>   Raven.Client.Linq.RavenQueryProvider`1.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute(Expression
>   expression)    at
>   Raven.Client.Linq.RavenQueryInspector`1.GetEnumerator()    at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1.InsertRange(Int32 index,
>   IEnumerable`1 collection)    at
>   NServiceBus.Timeout.Hosting.Windows.Persistence.RavenTimeoutPersistence.GetAll()
>   at NServiceBus.Timeout.Core.TimeoutRunner.CacheExistingTimeouts()
>   at NServiceBus.Timeout.Core.TimeoutRunner.Run()    at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1.ForEach(Action`1 action)    at
>   NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.NServiceBus.IStartableBus.Start(Action
>   startupAction)    at NServiceBus.Hosting.GenericHost.Start() in
>   c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\nsb.master_6\src\hosting\NServiceBus.Hostin
>   g\GenericHost.cs:line 34

Configuration of the host is:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();
container.Install(FromAssembly.This());

Configure.With()
    .DefiningEventsAs(t => t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.StartsWith("Events"))
    .DefiningCommandsAs(t => t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.StartsWith("Messages"))
    .CastleWindsorBuilder(container)
    .XmlSerializer()
    .MsmqTransport()
    .IsTransactional(true)
    .IsolationLevel(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted) 
    .UnicastBus()
    .RavenSagaPersister()
    .RavenSubscriptionStorage()
    .UseRavenTimeoutPersister()
    .RunTimeoutManager()
    .ForInstallationOn<NServiceBus.Installation.Environments.Windows>().Install();
```

I have other services on this machine that are running without error.  I've tried restarting the ravendb service.

Running Nservicebus 3.2.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing an index: RavenTimeoutPersistence/TimeoutDataSortedByTime

You need to create it, or NSB needs to create it, I am not sure where this index came from.

Comment: It came from NserviceBus, the timeout persister created it.  I had a look in raven & the index was there.

Comment: So I deleted it & recreated it & it started working.  Looks like the index got corrupted somehow

Comment: Yes, nsb should autocreate the index, curious on how it got corrupted? Was it a timing issue? Did you try to restart the endpoint more than once?

Comment: I tried restarting and reinstalling the service.  I restarted the raven service & got so frustrated I even restarted the box! Nothing worked, I had to go through & recreate the same index for 5 of the 7 service endpoints we have running.

Comment: The only thing that happened before it was the box hit 100% RAM usage, it was being over utilised.  The ravendb service stopped and after I restarted it was when the errors started.  I assume that was the cause

Comment: @AndreasÖhlund - I have no experience with RavenDB and I am getting this error.  (I assumed that NServiceBus encapuslated RavenDB away from me)  An explanation of how to recreate it would be nice.

Comment: I posted a question requesting a walkthrough of this process here:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/18898283/16241  If you are feeling kind, please consider answering it :)